I found a bound for roots in polynomial equation. Didn’t know if it is original.
One day I was trying to solve cubic equation without cubic formula(because it is computationally complicated and no algebraic way to denest cubic root). So I tried rational root theorem, which works when there is actually a rational root obviously. But sometimes the finite options that the theorem yield is a bit too much. So I have been working on ways to decrease the number of possibilities of roots.
And one of the ways is to find the bound of roots. And I’ve discover 2 bounds on my own. One of which is Cauchy’s bound, and the other… I can’t found it anywhere on the internet. And the proof is really easy unless I mess something up. So it would be very weird if no-one has found it yet. Anyways, here’s the bound:
For a degree n polynomial $$P(x)= a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + … + a_1 x + a_0,$$ every non zero roots of $P(x) = 0$ satisfies the boundary
$$ \frac 1 m \le |x| \le M $$
where
$$ M = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \sqrt[i\,]{\left | \frac{na_{n-i}}{a_n} \right | } $$
and
$$ m = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \sqrt[i\, ]{\left | \frac{na_i}{a_0} \right |}  $$
Proof:
Rewrite $P(x) = 0$ into
$$ n = -(\frac{na_{n-1}}{a_n} \frac 1 x + \frac{na_{n-2}}{a_n} \frac 1 {x^2} + … + \frac{na_{1}}{a_n} \frac 1 {x^{n-1}} + \frac{na_{0}}{a_n} \frac 1 {x^n})$$
by putting $x^n$ on LHS and everything else on RHS and divide both side by $x^n/n$
And if every terms on RHS is less than 1, then $P(x) \ne 0$ .
Any M larger than $$ \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \sqrt[i\, ]{\left | \frac{na_{n-i}}{a_n} \right | } $$ does that.
$$ n = \sum_{k=1}^n{1} = \sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{-na_{n-k}/{a_n}}{-na_{n-k}/{a_n}}} > \sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{-na_{n-k}/{a_n}}{M^k}} $$
Any $x$ larger or equal to M would be equality destroyer. Thus deriving the upper bound in the proof.
For lower bound, use $x=1/y$ substitution and apply upper bound to $y$’s polynomial.
Easy proof(if not wrong), the bound may seem bad at first. But you can optimize it in a few ways. Like vanishing the term that has the same sign as $a_n$. And cancel terms by grouping. But that isn’t the point today. New theorem, old theorem, or a false one? I am sure it wasn’t trivial. As it is quite useful.
Also I am just an high schooler, I haven’t learnt to write proof formally. And it is the first time of me using latex.
Edit:

If you feel like this might be new, how do I publish the result to let everyone know?
How can I strengthen the bound?(using maybe like the second largest coefficient or smth else)


Someone should add it here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots

No, wikipedia does not accept original research. It is not a mathematics journal.


Or il en résulte évidemment que la racine $\upsilon$ sera comprise entre le plus petit et le plus grand des nombres
$$n\rho_1,(n\rho_2)^{\tfrac{1}{2}},\ldots(n\rho_{n-1})^{\tfrac{1}{n-1}},(n\rho_n)^{\tfrac{1}{n}}\text{.}$$

—Cauchy's Sur la Résolution des Équation Numériques et Sur la Théorie de l'Élimination, Sec. 4, Eq. 18.
So no, not new. There are some minor improvements to be made from discarding coefficients with the "wrong" sign—any real $\upsilon$ such that
$$\upsilon^n-\rho_1\upsilon^{n-1} -\ldots-\rho_{n-1}\upsilon-\rho_n=0$$
must satisfy
$$\upsilon\leq\max_{i:\rho_i>0}\sqrt[i]{\#\{j|\rho_j>0\}\rho_i}\text{.}$$ Further reading:
Herman, Aaron and Hoon Hong (2016). "Quality of positive root bounds." Journal of Symbolic Computation.
74, 592-602.

Thanks, make sense that was already found. How do you find the source so quickly btw?

@Curryocity the bound is similar to one by Lagrange. Searching "variants Lagrange 'root bound'" on Google Scholar produced the paper by Herman and Hong as the first openly available relevant item, and their paper cites Cauchy's memoir for the given result. Scanning the section titles for relevance leads to the quoted passage.
